# Image processing app not working? appendChild(mySrcImg)?

Tags: javascript, canvas

I'm having a little trouble with my Javascript and HTML. It should work, with two pictures, but it doesn't. I've looked at the console in Chrome and it said that the "appendChild is null" or something like that.

For my safety, I can't give you the image, but I'm sure your images will work fine too for this small project. This is the code (it is quite big):

```js
var mySrcImg = new Image();
mySrcImg.crossOrigin = "";
mySrcImg.onload = test;
mySrcImg.src = "your image";

function test() {
  var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
  var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

  context.fillStyle = "rgb(0,200,0)";
  context.fillRect(0, 0, 800, 800);

  // Copy the image to the canvas
  context.drawImage(mySrcImg, 0, 0);

  // Get your image data
  var myImageData;
  myImageData = context.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  // Loop over each pixel and invert the colours
  var pixelComponents = myImageData.data;
  var n = pixelComponents.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < n; i += 4) {
    // One pixel:
    var average = (pixelComponents[i] +
      pixelComponents[i + 1] + pixelComponents[i + 2]) / 3;
    pixelComponents[i]; // red
    pixelComponents[i + 1]; // green
    pixelComponents[i + 2]; // blue
    // i+3 is alpha (the fourth element)

  }

  // Draw the ImageData object at the given (x,y) coordinates 
  context.putImageData(myImageData, 0, 0);

  document.getElementById("srcImgDiv").appendChild(mySrcImg);
}
```

```html
<h1 id="MyHeader">Image Processing App</h1>
<p><b>Original Image:</b></p>
<div id "='srcImgDiv'></div>
        
            <p><br></p>
        <p><b>Converted Image:</b></p>
            <canvas id="canvas " width="800 " height="800 "> </canvas>
            <p><br></p>
```

Comment: Careful, you have an extra `"` in `<div id "='srcImgDiv'></div>`. Should be `<div id='srcImgDiv'></div>`. For what you say the line `document.getElementById("srcImgDiv").appendChild(mySrcImg)` fails, so probably is this error.

Answer (score 1):

yeah,with given my image it is working totally fine. i just found 1 minor error that is:

```
<div id "='srcImgDiv'></div>
```

it should written as:

```
<div id ='srcImgDiv'></div>
```